# Cannot output all the data with the same id in modal

Tags: javascript, laravel

I wanted to make my message thread inside my modal. Upon clicking the button for modal I cannot get all the message with the same reference number. My codes executes the query first before receiving the refNumber that I pass to the controller. Please help me solve this issue.
These are my codes..

This is my controller (HomeController)

```
   public function getAllMessage(Request $request){
 $refNumber = $request->get('refNumber');



    $messageThread = DB::TABLE('i_di_thread')
     ->SELECT('message')
     ->WHERE('refNumber', $refNumber);
     return view ('showInquiries', ['messageThread'=>$messageThread]);

}
```

this is my javascript function

```
 $('#inquire_t tbody').on('click','#mensahe',function(){
           var refNumber = $(this).attr('value');

        getMessageThread(refNumber);

        function getMessageThread(refNumber){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getMessageThread',
                type: 'GET',
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN':$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                data: 'refNumber='+refNumber,
                dataType: 'text',
                success:function(msg){
                }//each
            });
        }
```

and this is my blade

```
 <!-- MODAL FOR MESSAGE THREAD -->
<div id="threadmessage" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3>Message Thread</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="height: 300px;" >
                <div class="row" style=" margin-left: 30px; margin-bottom: 5px; left: 20px; width: 550px; height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
                    <div>
                        @foreach ($messageThread as $thread)
                                {{$thread->message}}
                                <br>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="col-md-2"> 
                        <b> Message: </b><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10"> 
                        <textarea required=" " id="messageContent" style="resize: none;" class="form-control" rows="2"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div>
                    <button type="button" id="btn-message" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" style="background-color: #3c5fa6; color: white;"> 
                        Send <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"> </i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: All Ajax call are always asynchrone. the return values comes on success:function(msg){  --> put your code here !

Comment: It still give me an error of trying to getproperty of non-object

Comment: Of course, because the browser is a code interpreter, if the html part was not parsed when the js part run, they have no reality .  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DB::TABLE('i_di_thread')
     ->SELECT('message')
     ->WHERE('refNumber', $refNumber);
```

will return `Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder` instance. [Check here](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_where)

Add `->get()` to execute the query as a "select" statement. [Check here](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_get)

Complete code:

```
public function getAllMessage(Request $request){
    $refNumber = $request->get('refNumber');
    $messageThread = DB::table('i_di_thread')
                     ->select('message')
                     ->where('refNumber', $refNumber)
                     ->get();
    return view ('showInquiries', ['messageThread'=>$messageThread]);

}
```

**UPDATED**

You are displaying data with blade and is not asynchronously.

[Check this answer if you want to dynamically get data and to display in modal.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43981659/6887746)

**Note:**
 Use [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-optional) function to access property without causing error.

**Example:**

```
<div class="row" style=" margin-left: 30px; margin-bottom: 5px; left: 20px; width: 550px; height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
                    <div>
                        @foreach ($messageThread as $thread)
                                {{optional($thread)->message}} {{-- accessing property without causing error --}}
                                <br>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public function getAllMessage(Request $request){
 $refNumber = $request->get('refNumber');



    $messageThread = DB::TABLE('i_di_thread')
     ->SELECT('message')
     ->WHERE('refNumber', $refNumber)->get();
     return view ('showInquiries', ['messageThread'=>$messageThread]);

}
```